# How do I replace prototype on a single page of my rails 2.3 application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, prototype, sugar.js

I'm trying to use sugar.js, but Prototype's camelize method is getting in the way of sugar's.
Any alternative solutions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: PrototypeJS + Sugar.js? Sounds like a mix meant for disaster.

Comment: @elclanrs: Agreed. Unfortunately, I was stuck in this world of pain :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.sugarRestore('camelize')
```

is what fixes my specific problem but I'd still like to know if there's a way to replace or remove prototype for a single page. So I'll leave the question open a little longer.